# Show Difference Between TSV by Column

Tags: awk, sed, diff

I'm comparing two TSV files that are package lists generated like so:

```
rpm -qa --qf "%{name}\t%{version}\t%{license}\n" | sort -n > packages
```

This generates a tab separated file, for example:

```
alsa-firmware   1.0.28  GPL+ and BSD and GPLv2+ and GPLv2 and LGPLv2+
alsa-lib        1.0.28  LGPLv2+
alsa-tools-firmware     1.0.27  GPLv2+
```

On another system I'm running the same command where there are considerably more packages installed. I want a list of those additional packages on the second server. The tricky part here is that I want the match list to NOT filter by version. Comm and Diff check the whole line and I only want to filter by the first "column".

For instance, if the second server has the following package list:

```
acl     2.2.51  GPLv2+
alsa-firmware   2.0.28  GPL+ and BSD and GPLv2+ and GPLv2 and LGPLv2+
alsa-lib        2.0.29  LGPLv2+
alsa-tools-firmware     2.0.27  GPLv2+
audit   2.4.1   GPLv2+
binutils        2.23.52.0.1     GPLv3+
```

I'm looking for a command (sed, awk, comm, diff, etc) that would return the difference by the First Column - which in this case would be:

```
acl     2.2.51  GPLv2+
audit   2.4.1   GPLv2+
binutils        2.23.52.0.1     GPLv3+
```

**Notice that the alsa packages have changed versions but still have the same package names.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `awk`, matching only first columns in both files

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} !($1 in a)' file1 file2
acl     2.2.51  GPLv2+
audit   2.4.1   GPLv2+
binutils        2.23.52.0.1     GPLv3+
```

Or passing first column as search pattern to `grep`. This assumes that other columns in `file2` won't match with the search terms

```
$ awk '{print $1}' file1 | grep -vFf - file2
acl     2.2.51  GPLv2+
audit   2.4.1   GPLv2+
binutils        2.23.52.0.1     GPLv3+
```

with `sed`, similar to `grep` solution but prone to error if first column of `file1` contains any regex meta characters

```
$ sed -f <(sed -E 's|^(\S+).*|/\1/d|' file1) file2
acl     2.2.51  GPLv2+
audit   2.4.1   GPLv2+
binutils        2.23.52.0.1     GPLv3+
```

Comment: The first command, awk on it's own, is the correct approach but the `++` is doing nothing except using up cycles. The awk+grep should not be used as it will falsely compare/match across whole lines instead of just the first field, and the nested seds should be avoid for the reasons you stated plus others.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks, I didn't know that `a[$1]` was enough :)

Comment: Great work guys! awk indeed gave me the results I was looking for.